# How to access the content of an iframe with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, iframe

How can I access the content of an iframe with jQuery? I tried doing this, but it wouldn't work:

**iframe content:** `<div id="myContent"></div>`

**jQuery:** `$("#myiframe").find("#myContent")`

How can I access `myContent`?

---

> **Similar to** [jquery/javascript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe) but the accepted answer is not what I was looking for.

Comment: I just found that the built-in $ variable in Firefox console does not look like a complete jQuery at all.  (I figured this after realizing that I do not have the jQuery variable either, then figuring that I did not load jQuery's source code).

Answer (score 242, accepted):

You have to use the `contents()` method:

```
$("#myiframe").contents().find("#myContent")
```

Source: [https://web.archive.org/web/20180608003357/http://simple.procoding.net/2008/03/21/how-to-access-iframe-in-jquery/](http://simple.procoding.net/2008/03/21/how-to-access-iframe-in-jquery/)

API Doc: https://api.jquery.com/contents/

Comment: give me error: Error: Permission denied to access property 'ownerDocument'

Comment: ime: Its probably giving you error because of following reasons: 1) Iframe doesn't belong to same domain. 2) You are trying to read it before Iframe load event.

Comment: Is there a way to verify if the iframe content is from the same domain, prior to trying to access it and getting an error?

Comment: The source url is broken.

Comment: @iMatoria What to do for the 1 reasson?

Comment: @jperezmartin: You will have to use some javascript library that will transfer information between main page and iframe. Basically its been denied by browser because of Cross Browser functionality. I am sorry, I am not aware of any such library because I never required it.

Comment: @mbillard I am loading iframe with src so how can I access the contents as it is not having neither innerHTML nor innerText. both contains src values but not the actual page

Comment: Is this possible if the iframe has sandbox attribute with `allow-script`?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/a/1639342/1175496

Answer (score 24):

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    //here you have the control over the body of the iframe document
    var iBody = $("#iView").contents().find("body");

    //here you have the control over any element (#myContent)
    var myContent = iBody.find("#myContent");

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe src="mifile.html" id="iView" style="width:200px;height:70px;border:dotted 1px red" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 18):

If iframe's source is an external domain, browsers will hide the iframe contents (Same Origin Policy).
A workaround is saving the external contents in a file, for example (in PHP):

```
<?php
    $contents = file_get_contents($external_url);
    $res = file_put_contents($filename, $contents);
?>
```

then, get the new file content (string) and parse it to html, for example (in jquery):

```
$.get(file_url, function(string){
    var html = $.parseHTML(string);
    var contents = $(html).contents();
},'html');
```