# set field values in a wufoo form in an iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

i need to set the value/values of a form select field in an iframe using jquery.

how can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

If you know what to do with jquery once you have access to the iframe - this thread should help:

[How to access the content of an iframe with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796619/how-to-access-the-content-of-an-iframe-with-jquery)

**Caveat:** This is probably going to be a problem cross-domain, so you may be out of luck

[jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-iframe-cross-domain