# How to get editor object in twitter Bootstrap WYSIWYG5

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, textarea, wysiwyg

I am using Bootstrap wysiwyg5 editor as a part of a form.

This text area happens to be a required field(should not be empty). I want to validate if the user has entered any value on to this field or not. I see that Bootstrap wysiwyg uses a Iframe to display the content. I tried to access the content of the iframe's body in jQuery by doing this:

```
$('.textarea.wysihtml5-editor').html()
```

but failed.

My question is: How do I check if the user has entered some text in this Bootstrap wysiwyg textarea. Please help me out.

Comment: How you are initializing it?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I don't see any iframes in their demo. It's just a div that is `contenteditable`

Comment: yes, I see a iframe which it uses to display the content.

Comment: http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/ - There is no iframe. It's `<div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>`

Comment: @lan ah.. yours seem to be little different from what am using : http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/

Comment: @codeMan Ooohh, I had no idea there were 2! Sorry for the confusion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this question?

[How to access the content of an iframe with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796619/how-to-access-the-content-of-an-iframe-with-jquery)

The answer from the question referenced above:

```
$("#myiframe").contents().find("#myContent")
```

Edited to add my original answer:

```
$('.textarea.wysihtml5-editor').val()
```

Comment: WOW!! it worked!!only god knows how long I have been stuck with this.... thanks a lot!!

Comment: can you included the statement in your answer that u had written before, so that I can accept the answer?

Comment: What I had written before was before I realized you were referring to a iframe.  Do I need to write some code in there for it to be accepted?

Comment: I just appended the answer from the link that I referenced from @mbillard.

Comment: Oh, that's great.  Glad I could help.  I'm sure we all know how it feels to spin on something when you're only a step away.  I added my original answer too.

Answer (score 1):

wysiwyg editor does not works in bootstrap modal because it triggers before creating modal.. or something. so the best way to do it is triggering the modal before wysiwyg editor.

```
function showmymodal(){
$('#modal').modal('show');
$("#modal").html(' <div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h3 id="myModalLabel">modal header</h3></div>
<div class="modal-body">
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
</div>
</form>');
$('#textarea').wysihtml5({
"font-styles": true, 
"emphasis": true,
"lists": true, 
"html": false, 
"link": true, 
"image": true, 
"color": true 
});
}
```

you can check on 
[Tutorial website](http://www.oykko.com/question/13)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please summarise the link in your answer; that way, if the link goes stale the answer won't be completely useless.

Comment: @Debashis Dip Thanks for your answer. That was not my concern, I was not trying make WYSIHTML5 work in a Modal.

Comment: sorry,for checking iframe val you should use
$("#textarea").val();