# Iframe selector jquery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have a html code like :

```
<div id="a">
<div id="b">
<iframe id="demo" />

</div>
</div>
```

How can I refer the iframe element using jquery?

I have tried  `jQuery("#demo").bind(.)`, but It doesn't work.

Comment: Does this link answer your question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796619/how-to-access-the-content-of-an-iframe-with-jquery

Comment: @Adam : MY question is other way round!!
I need to select iframe present within those two div's

Comment: Note: your iframe is within a div within a div, maybe you should try telling jquery where to find it, rather then just what id to find.

Comment: @amber: according to you,it should be jQuery("#a #b #demo") ??

Comment: @Sibendu Yes, that should work. You can use the `$` sign instead of `jQuery` to save space if you want. If it doesn't work, you can try glueing some `.find()`s after it

Comment: Also note that your current `bind(.)` won't do anything as it doesn't contain a function to bind to the iframe.

Comment: yes bind(.) I have just kept blank.Actually I'm using click event along with that.Hope it works!!

Comment: No it is not working!!.Actually there is another div having id as "a".Iam unsure whether this is causing the problem