# jQuery: change the image of an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe from anoter page in another domain.:

For example:

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="http://stackoverflow.com/">
</iframe>
```

and in jQuery, i have this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myframe").load(function(){
        var obj = $("#myframe").contents().find('#hlogo');

        div.append('<img src="http://www.my-domain.com/img/myimage.jpg" />');
    });

});
```

But it is not adding an image. What can I do?

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hGAp6/), I am trying to change the image to something else -Same problem, different sources.

Comment: I think it has something to do with [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules).

Comment: try with this first:
frames['nameOfMyIframe']
If this is undefined than it should be SOP as Dave Chen suggested!

Comment: It is impossible to do. You can not touch the content of another domain.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the src attribute of #hlogo you need to do like so :

```
var iframe = $('<iframe>', {
       id:  'pay-rent',
       }).appendTo('body');


       iframe.load(function(){
        var obj = $('#pageHeaderLogo',iframe.contents());
        console.log(obj);
        obj.attr('src', 'http://www.firstchoicehousing.com/images/logo.png');
    });

iframe.attr({
 src:"http://wemanageproperties.securecafe.com/residentservices/apartmentsforrent/userlogin.asp"
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UYPTc/
If the iframe is different domain, you cannot access the contents of it due to [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://fiddle.jshell.net" from accessing a frame with origin "http://wemanageproperties.reslisting.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Answer (score -1):

you can use jQuery.contents() function

docs: 
http://api.jquery.com/contents/

see also
[How to access the content of an iframe with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796619/how-to-access-the-content-of-an-iframe-with-jquery)