# Load iframe content with Javascript (or jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I need read a external code that comes through a file that is in the same folder of the html file. The problem is that the HTML isn't running in a server, so I can't use the jQuery load() and other solutions. So I think in load the code via an iframe like this:

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="script1.html"></iframe>
```

The text in the file is something like this:

```
One paragraph. Some words
Other paragraph, and more words...
```

I need get the sentences and throw in a array, but I even can't get the text via jQuery. I'm trying do this:

```
var text = $("#iframe").val();
```

But it does nothing, so I tried this inserting the html tags in the file:

```
$('#iframe').contents().find("html").html();
```

And nothing again. So, how to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access the content of an iframe with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796619/how-to-access-the-content-of-an-iframe-with-jquery)

Comment: I already saw this solution, but it the code mentioned gives me "undefined", and if I run the code seconds after the page load, the Chrome gives me this error: "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match."

Comment: $($('#iframe').get(0).contentWindow.document).find('body').text().
you can use contentWindow to access to window object of iframe.
But your page and iframe must in a same domain with same protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a simple $.ajax post/get call ? Instead of .load, .ajax will process any JS & HTML in script1.html

somehing like :

`$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url:"script1.html",
dataType:"html",
success: function(data) {
// do what you want here
}});`

Baptiste

Answer (score 0):

you can get your value by the following:

```
 var iBody = $("#iframe").contents().find("body");

//here you have the control over your element (#myContent)
var myContent = iBody.find("#myContent"); //store it in variable here where myContent is the div id you want to get value of..
```