# Issue with iframe and jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, iframe

I'd like to parse my iframe using jquery, I need for example to search in the iframe document the string "Ctrl".

Url of my iframe : http://windows.microsoft.com/fr-xf/internet-explorer/ie-keyboard-shortcuts#ie=ie-11

```
$('#iframeIe').contents()
```

Error message :

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:4000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.(…)
```

Is there any other method to include websites on a page and parse them? I mean parse their text contents...

Comment: is the frame on the same domain or can you modify the cors header?

Comment: The iframe is not on the same domaine, i'm on my local server...

Comment: can only do this if you control both domains

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

You can try the snippet of this thread :

```
$(function(){//document ready
    $('some selector', frames['nameOfMyIframe'].document).doStuff()
});
```

Or take a look at the answers if you have the [permission denied errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Answer (score -2):

You can use AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "yourwebsiteurl",
  async: false,
  dataType: 'html',
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    $(".div").append(html); // for example append your html to a specific object 
  }
});
```

Keep in mind that you can only get data from pages that are within the same domain otherwise it will complain about cross-browser origin kind of annoying stuff ;).

Comment: I'm not on the same domain, i'm on my local server.

Comment: ajax won't solve cross domain problem, it is bound to same security policy

Comment: an is there any other solution to parse the iframe?

Comment: I would say have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796619/how-to-access-the-content-of-an-iframe-with-jquery) @tonymx227