# Check for element inside an iframe exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a iframe embeded in my page. I saw an paper icon with sad face in it.

[image]

I inspect it, it has an id `#sub-frame-error-details`

---

## iFrame

```
<iframe id="iframe-rm" name="my-iframe" src="https://192.237.175.25:555/" width="100%" height="800px" class=""></iframe>
```

---

## Try #1

`console.log($('#sub-frame-error-details').length);`

I kept getting 0.

---

## Try #2

`document.getElementById("sub-frame-error-details")`

I got `null`

---

## Try #3

`var obj = $("#iframe-rm").contents().find("#main-frame-error");`

`console.log(obj.length);`

still get `0` print out.

How do I detect if it's there ?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796619/how-to-access-the-content-of-an-iframe-with-jquery

Comment: I tried `var obj = $("#iframe-rm").contents().find("#main-frame-error");
console.log(obj.length);` , and I still getting `0` - while knowing for sure that it is there.

Comment: Are the contents of the iframe cross-domain? If so, you can't access their contents and it will give you either a 0 or a null return depending on the way you try to access it.

Comment: Expanding on Joe's comment is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe

Comment: Yes, they're cross domain. So how would go above and detect something like that ? Is it impossible ? Please advise.