# Get text from selector in jquery - wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I want to take the text of first row from `body` in wordpress and I have some problems.

My code: 
HTML CODE

```
<body id='asd'>
   <h2>Text1</h2>
   <p>Text2</p>
   <b>Text3</b>
</body>
```

JS CODE:

```
console.log(jQuery('#asd').children(':first').text());
```

This code is working locally. It will output in console, exactly what I need:
**Text1**, but, in wordpress doesn't work.

If I try the same code on wordpress, no output is show.

If i try:

```
console.log(jQuery('#asd').children(':first'));
```

On local output is: `[h2, prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]`
On wordpress output is: `[selector: "", prevObject: a.fn.init, context: document]`

Can someone help?

Comment: According to your output mentioned above the element is not present on the DOM. Can you provide some more details on the how is the html structure on your wordpress site.

Comment: @HarshitJain I don't understand your question..

Comment: has wordpress removed the id from your body? why not just try `$('body').children().eq(0)`.  Is that the fullpage in wordpress? - ie you are not trying to use multiple body tags?

Comment: @Pete There are multiple body tags... And that id isn't removed, it's still there.

Comment: html documents can only have one body tag - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body, perhaps you should use an article tag instead

Comment: It's wordpress.. i can't change the 2nd body. Is already made by wordpress itself

Comment: Well you have to change something as your code is invalid and that's why it's not working

Comment: And its something like that:
`<html>
<body>
<iframe>
<html>
<body>SomethingHere</body>
</html>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: @Kiddo: The element `#asd` is present on your local but not on the wordpress site and hence the `[selector: "", prevObject: a.fn.init, context: document]` output.
This output states that the element `#asd` is not present. Can you please check in the browser console by searching for `asd`.

Comment: You had right. Can you get somehow the first element from the second body? Or it's not possible?

Comment: if it is in an iframe then it is okay - to get content out of an iframe, you need to target the frame - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796619/how-to-access-the-content-of-an-iframe-with-jquery

Comment: It's working ! Thank you a lot, @Pete

Comment: Thank you too, @HarshitJain

Comment: Can you put a new answer, with what you said, to close this topic? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, it looks as if the body is in a separate iframe that is within the main document.  To target an iframe's contents you need to do the following:

```
$('#iframe-id').contents().find('#asd').children(':first').text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#asd:first-child').text();
}
```

It will return the first children tag value.

Comment: Output is empty string.. But on local it will return correct answer >.<

Comment: Also try :first-child

Comment: The same answer... it returns an empty string :(

Comment: checking up now

Comment: $ (Document) .ready (function () { // correct it to jQuery instead of $

Comment: Yeah, but on wordpress isn't working... that's what i m saying

Comment: Can you remove this <Script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"> </ script> and try

Comment: This is local: http://i67.tinypic.com/2hp3pdv.png and this is on wordpress: http://i63.tinypic.com/16k7xqw.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143686/discussion-between-ahmed-ginani-and-kiddo).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put code in jQuery document ready event. Your code may execute before body tag loaded in DOM.

Comment: Tried 

    `jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
       // code here
    });`

and still nothing