# How to reference a website loaded with JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have used JQuery to load a website, like this:

```
$("#external-site")
   .html('<object class="website" data="http://www.example.com'"><object/>');
```

into the `#external-site` div. This puts an `<object>` into the `#external-site` div and inside that is a html document which looks like this: `#document`. I want to attach an on click event to an element in the document. I have tried things like this:

```
$( ".myDiv" ).on( "click", function() {
    console.log("hello")
});
```

Then, I tried a delegated event:

```
$( "#document" ).on( "click", ".myDiv", function() {
    console.log("hello")
});
```

But neither would log to the console when I click on the `.myDiv` element. Am I referencing the `#document` correctly? Is it possible what I am trying to do?

Comment: usually document will be selected as $(document).. Is there any element in your html holds document as id?

Comment: I tried selecting it like that but it didn't work. There is no element with document as id.

Comment: Depending on the security settings of the third party website you may be being blocked by the SOP and various other cross-domain security measures. Check the console for errors. Unless the website you're loading expressly allows themselves to be loaded in an iframe and have the content amended by an external source (which is *highly* unlikely) then this will most likely not work

Comment: Ah ok. If the iframe content is on the same domain it should work. Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796619/how-to-access-the-content-of-an-iframe-with-jquery

Comment: Sorry, it is not on the same domain but i created it and it is on a different domain.

Comment: Ok, in that case you need to set your content to the correct security settings. The issue will 100% be down to the Same Origin Policy (SOP)

Answer (score 0):

```
 I have made this in jsfiddle. Is this what you are looking for?
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s1Lyr9at/1/

Comment: Post the code here, not just at jsfiddle. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable. And the text of your answer should not be put into a code block.

Comment: I joined stackoverflow just 3 days before. I dont aware of stack snippets and comment aligning