# How jquery or javascript access DOM in iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want `jquery` or `javascript` to access `DOM` in `Iframe`.

For example, I make a iframe to show amazon.
then I wanna get a banner image link on amazon.
Can I do this?

and I have one more problem.
if I click amazon banner that is made a by _blank target on "a" Tag in a iframe,
browser make a new tab. but I wanna see a new page in a iframe.

Comment: To open a link in an iframe, use the name of an existing iframe as the target instead of "_blank".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the content of an iframe with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796619/how-to-access-the-content-of-an-iframe-with-jquery). But the page and iframe content should be from same domain.

Comment: @Alexander More relevant dupe would then be: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe

Comment: @A.Wolff , I was adding similar comment to my flag.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that if the origin of the iframe is different from the parent document :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: As a side node, it is possible in some cases athought that implies the iframed page needs to expose [window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). Anyway your answer regarding amazon is correct!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
and I just decided to use request module. and show using echo html source on child page.