# jQuery + SVG: unable to access SVG element in iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, iframe

Questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796619/how-to-access-the-content-of-an-iframe-with-jquery) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe) say using jQuery `contents()` lets you access an iFrame element.

However, this code isn't working.

It isn't an cross-origin issue as both parent and iFrame are hosted on the Codepen.io domain.

If you view the Codepen, you can see the iFrame has a child SVG element called `designBox`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

          $("#livePreview").on("load", function() {
             var designBox = $("#livePreview").contents().find("#designBox");
             var livePreviewContents = $("#livePreview").contents();

             console.log("Loaded live preview. Design box: " + designBox.length + ". Live preview contents: " + livePreviewContents);
          });

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be facing same origin policy issue.
You can't access the contents of an iframe with different origin using JavaScript, it would be a huge security flaw if you could do it. For the same-origin policy browsers block scripts trying to access a frame with a different origin.

I am sharing a link where it is explained in detail to access the content of an iframe and various scenarios
[Follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-the-bodys-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript)

Comment: both parent and iframe are from the same domain (codepen.io).

Comment: @Crashalot nope, your code is running from `https://s.codepen.io`, while the iframe you load is hosted by `https://codepen.io` subdomains are not same domain.

Comment: @Kaiido please post an answer so you can get credit. thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Kaiido would love to credit you so hopefully you can post an answer when you get a moment. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at your developer tools, you'll notice there is a middle iFrame with id `result` that is added by Codepen. This because the iframe you add is a codepen page that also already contains an iframe.

The structure is like :

```
|--- iframe#livePreview -------|
| |--- iframe#result --------| |
| | |--- svg#designBox ----| | |
| | |                      | | |
| | |______________________| | |
| |__________________________| |
|______________________________|
```

So you'll need to add another `contents()` call to go inside this `iframe#result` and then get your `svg`.

=> `$("#livePreview").contents().find("#result").contents().find("#designBox");`
But you probably will have to manage the `load` event of the nested iframe (I haven't tested it)

Comment: Unfortunately, codepen does execute `#result` frame on a subdomain, so this won't work, even though it was spot on too.